# Why Xcode7.1 can not bind 1 gestureRecognizer to 2 objects

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgrade xcode from 6 to 7.1. After that I found a strange problem. I bind a gesture recognizer to 2 objects(1 label and 1 imageView), to make an action to be triggered by tapping either one of the two objects. 
[I set up these in the stroyboard like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OHqm.png)

This works fine with xcode 6. But after upgrading, the action is triggered only by tapping one of the two objects. Tapping on the other object gets no response.

I tried to delete the outlet collections and re-add them, the problem is just the same.

Am I unproperly doing this? Or is this a bug of xcode 7.1? 
How to resolve it?
Looking forward to your help.

BTW: I am writing with Swift, just upgraded to Swift 2 at the same time I upgrade the xcode.

Comment: Every gesture recognizer is associated with one view. By contrast, a view can have multiple gesture recognizers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your project. But in the Apple docs:

> Every gesture recognizer is associated with one view.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html